# What dependencies must be added to make Hibernate and Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I am trying to add dependencies to my project. I already added the maven plugin to my eclipse from this link http://eclipse.org/m2e/

Here is my generated **pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>dddddd</groupId>
  <artifactId>ss</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>ss</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

But I am trying to add different dependencies like **mysql-connector-java** + **hibernate** + **spring**

I am able to add some of these dependencies. Could you please tell me what added dependencies are required to make a simple MVC project using Spring  with Hibernate + SQL?  After adding the proper dependencies I am trying to make my first project.

Here is my attempt to update **pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>dddddd</groupId>
  <artifactId>ss</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>ss</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- spring dependancy -->
        <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.6</version>
                 </dependency>



                 <dependency>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                 </dependency>
    <!-- spring dependancy -->

  <!-- Hibernate annotation -->
  <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
                    <artifactId>
                        hibernate-commons-annotations
                    </artifactId>
                    <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
                 </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy end -->

                 <!-- sql dependency -->

         <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
                 <!-- sql dependency end -->



  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Pet-clinic as reference.. Here are list of dependencies

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/pom.xml

Hope that helps